# one-way binding : how to update model when view input element is updated (and not do vise versa)

Tags: vue.js

I am looking for a kind of one-way binding to update model when a number input value is updated and at the same time prevent input element from being updated when model is changed (disable vise versa).
Using **v-model** is a 2-way method which I don't want. Using **:value** is also the opposite way. Can someone write an example?

Comment: `v-model` is just a shorthand for using a prop (usually `value`) and an event (usually `input`). It sounds like you just need the event.

Answer (score 1):

The `v-model` implementation is only syntactic sugar, where can be replaced using `:value` and `@input`.

For example:

```
  <input type="text" :value="value" />
  {{ value }}
  <button @click="value++">add +</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/raulghm/yxpgdf9m/1